# Class 'Router' not found in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.3

I am upgrading my cakephp version from 2.6.7 to 3.3.4. The following code was properly working to refer the home url:

```
<?php echo Router::url('/', true); ?>
```

But this not working in cakephp 3.3.4 and it shows the following error message:

```
Error: Class 'Router' not found
```

Which I missed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this `<?= $this->Url->build('/', true) ?>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make yourself comfortable with PHP namespaces. The `Router` class lives in the `Cake\Routing` namespace, hence you have to use either:

```
\Cake\Routing\Router::url()
```

or import the class:

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
```

That being said, in your views you may want to use the `Url` helper instead (as mentioned by Jacek B Budzynski in the comments), in order to avoid the hard dependency on the `Router` class:

```
$this->Url->build('/', true)
```

See also

- **[PHP Manual > Language Reference > Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)**
- **[Cookbook > 3.x Migration Guide > 3.0 Migration Guide > Namespaces](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#namespaces)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Url](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html)**